# Do the JMS spec or the various implementations support delivery confirmation of messages?

Tags: jms

Lets say Producer sends a message to the JMS Topic "news". Consumer1 reads the message, but Consumer2 is offline so he hasn't read the message yet.

Is there any build-in (to the spec or impl) way for the Producer to be notified that Consumer1 has read his message, but Consumer2 has not? This would, in fact, mirror the Read Notification of an email.

Clearly you could implement this by having each Consumer send an acknowledgement, but I'm looking for something already a part of JMS or a JMS system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JMS FAQ](http://java.sun.com/products/jms/faq.html#end_to_end) says

> JMS API messaging provides guaranteed
>   delivery via the once-and-only-once
>   delivery semantics of PERSISTENT
>   messages. In addition, message
>   consumers can insure reliable
>   processing of messages by using either
>   CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode or transacted
>   sessions. This achieves reliable
>   delivery with minimum synchronization
>   and is the enterprise messaging model
>   most vendors and developers prefer.
>
> The JMS API does not define a schema
>   of systems messages (such as delivery
>   notifications). If an application
>   requires acknowledgment of message
>   receipt, it can define an
>   application-level acknowledgment
>   message.
>
> These issues are more clearly
>   understood when they are examined in
>   the context of publish/subscribe
>   applications. In this context,
>   synchronous delivery and/or system
>   acknowledgment of receipt are not an
>   effective mechanism for implementing
>   reliable applications (because
>   producers by definition are not, and
>   do not want to be, responsible for
>   end-to-end message delivery).

I'm no expert, but I think this is saying that the spec doesn't define a way for a consumer to confirm receipt to a producer, by design. I don't know of any implementations that do - and if they did, it looks like it'd be a big departure from the model the spec captures.